# Nested objects using Room in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have 4 different objects (RoomHospital, RoomProcedimento, RoomConvenio, and RoomLancamento). The first 3 ones have basically an id and a name. The last one should have an id and an instance of each of the previous ones.

Example for the first 3 objects

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "convenios_table")
data class RoomConvenio(
    @NotNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_convenio")
    var id: Int = 0,

    @NotNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nome_convenio")
    var nomeConvenio: String
) : Parcelable
```

Example of the last one:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "lancamentos_table")
data class RoomLancamento(
    @NotNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_lancamento")
    var id : Int = 0,

    @NotNull
    @ForeignKey(
        entity = RoomHospital::class,
        childColumns = ["id_hospital_FK"],
        parentColumns = ["id_hospital"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "hospital_FK")
    var hospital : RoomHospital,

    @NotNull
    @ForeignKey(
        entity = RoomProcedimento::class,
        parentColumns = ["id_procedimento"],
        childColumns = ["id_procedimento_FK"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_procedimento_FK")
    var idProcedimento : Int,

    @NotNull
    @ForeignKey(
        entity = RoomConvenio::class,
        parentColumns = ["id_convenio"],
        childColumns = ["id_convenio_FK"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_convenio_FK")
    var idConvenio : Int
) : Parcelable
```

What I want to have as a final result is:
In RoomLancamento table (lancamentos_table) I want to have just the reference of the other tables PK ids like:

[image: How I want info to be stored]

But when I retrieve these keys from the db, I want to have the whole object that they were referencing, something like:

[image: Final result expected]

How should this be done?

Comment: use foreign keys for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could have a standard class that includes the underlying/referenced objects and that instantiation is via a RoonLancamento object.

For example something along the lines of :-

```
class Together {

    var hospital: RoomHospital? = null
    var convenio: RoomConvenio? = null
    var procedimento: RoomProcedimento? = null

    constructor() {}

    constructor(allDao: AllDao, lancamento: RoomLancamento) {

        this.hospital = allDao.getRoomHospitalById(lancamento.getHospital())
        this.convenio = allDao.getRoomConvenioById(lancamento.idConvenio)
        this.procedimento = allDao.getRoomProcedimentoById(lancamento.idProcedimento)
    }
}
```

So you query the database and return a RoomLancamento object which you then use to Contsruct a Together object (an instance of the Dao being passed (in this case an AllDao object)). Constructing the object calls the respective queries to retrieve the respective object accord to it's id.

The following is an example (but in Java rather than Kotlin) :-

### RoomHospital.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "hospital_table")
public class RoomHospital {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_hospital")
    long id;
    String name;

    public RoomHospital(){}

    @Ignore
    public RoomHospital(String hospitalName) {
        this.name = hospitalName;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

### RoomConvenio.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "convenios_table")
public class RoomConvenio {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_convenio")
    long id = 0;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nome_convenio")
    String nomeConvenio;

    public RoomConvenio() {}

    @Ignore
    public RoomConvenio(String convenioName) {
        this.nomeConvenio = convenioName;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getNomeConvenio() {
        return nomeConvenio;
    }

    public void setNomeConvenio(@NonNull String nomeConvenio) {
        this.nomeConvenio = nomeConvenio;
    }
}
```

### RoomProcedimento.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "procedimento_table")
public class RoomProcedimento {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_procedimento")
    long id_procedimento;
    String nameProcedimento;

    public RoomProcedimento() {}

    @Ignore
    public RoomProcedimento(String procedimentoName) {
        this.nameProcedimento = procedimentoName;
    }

    public long getId_procedimento() {
        return id_procedimento;
    }

    public void setId_procedimento(long id_procedimento) {
        this.id_procedimento = id_procedimento;
    }

    public String getNameProcedimento() {
        return nameProcedimento;
    }

    public void setNameProcedimento(String nameProcedimento) {
        this.nameProcedimento = nameProcedimento;
    }
}
```

### RoomLancamento.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "lancamentos_table")
public class RoomLancamento {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_lancamento")
    long id;

    @ForeignKey(
            entity = RoomHospital.class,
            parentColumns = {"id_hospital"},
            childColumns = {"id_hospital_FK"}
            /* , onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL WILL BE PROBLEMATIC */
    )
    @ColumnInfo(name = "hospital_FK")
    long hospital;

    @ForeignKey(
            entity = RoomProcedimento.class,
            parentColumns = {"id_procedimento"},
            childColumns = {"id_procedimento_FK"}
            /* ,onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL */
    )
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_procedimento_FK")
    long idProcedimento;

    @ForeignKey(
            entity = RoomConvenio.class,
            parentColumns = {"id_convenio"},
            childColumns = {"id_convenio_FK"}
            /* , onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL */
    )
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_convenio_FK")
    long idConvenio;


    public RoomLancamento() {}

    @Ignore
    public RoomLancamento(long hospitalId, long conevioId, long procedimentoId) {
        this.hospital = hospitalId;
        this.idConvenio = conevioId;
        this.idProcedimento = procedimentoId;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }

    public void setHospital(long hospital) {
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }

    public long getIdConvenio() {
        return idConvenio;
    }

    public void setIdConvenio(long idConvenio) {
        this.idConvenio = idConvenio;
    }

    public long getIdProcedimento() {
        return idProcedimento;
    }

    public void setIdProcedimento(long idProcedimento) {
        this.idProcedimento = idProcedimento;
    }
}
```

### AllDao.java

```
@Dao
public interface AllDao {

    @Insert
    long[] insertRoomHospitals(RoomHospital... roomHospitals);

    @Insert
    long insertRoomHospital(RoomHospital roomHospital);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM hospital_table WHERE id_hospital = :hospitalId")
    RoomHospital getRoomHospitalById(long hospitalId);

    @Query("SELECT count() FROM hospital_table")
    int getRoomHospitalRowCount();

    @Insert
    long[] insertRoomConvenios(RoomConvenio... roomConvenios);

    @Insert
    long insertRoomConvenio(RoomConvenio roomConvenio);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM convenios_table WHERE id_convenio = :convenioId")
    RoomConvenio getRoomConvenioById(long convenioId);


    @Insert
    long[] insertRoomProcedimentos(RoomProcedimento... roomProcedimentos);

    @Insert
    long insertRoomProcedimento(RoomProcedimento roomProcedimento);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM procedimento_table WHERE id_procedimento = :procedimentoId")
    RoomProcedimento getRoomProcedimentoById(long procedimentoId);

    @Insert
    long insertRoomLancamento(RoomLancamento roomLancamento);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM lancamentos_table")
    List<RoomLancamento> getAllLancamentos();
}
```

### AllTogether.java

```
public class AllTogether {

    private RoomHospital hospital;
    private RoomConvenio convenio;
    private RoomProcedimento procedimento;

    public AllTogether() {}

    public AllTogether(AllDao allDao, RoomLancamento lancamento) {

        this.hospital = allDao.getRoomHospitalById(lancamento.getHospital());
        this.convenio = allDao.getRoomConvenioById(lancamento.idConvenio);
        this.procedimento = allDao.getRoomProcedimentoById(lancamento.idProcedimento);
    }

    public RoomHospital getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }

    public void setHospital(RoomHospital hospital) {
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }

    public RoomConvenio getConvenio() {
        return convenio;
    }

    public void setConvenio(RoomConvenio convenio) {
        this.convenio = convenio;
    }

    public RoomProcedimento getProcedimento() {
        return procedimento;
    }

    public void setProcedimento(RoomProcedimento procedimento) {
        this.procedimento = procedimento;
    }
}
```

### TheDatabase.java

```
@Database(version = 1, entities = {
        RoomHospital.class,
        RoomConvenio.class,
        RoomProcedimento.class,
        RoomLancamento.class
})
public abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    abstract AllDao allDao();
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao allDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,TheDatabase.class,"mydb")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        allDao = db.allDao();
        addSomeData();
        List<RoomLancamento> RoomLancamentosList = allDao.getAllLancamentos();
        ArrayList<AllTogether> allTogetherList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (RoomLancamento rl: RoomLancamentosList) {
            allTogetherList.add(new AllTogether(allDao,rl));
        }

        for (AllTogether a: allTogetherList) {
            Log.d(
                    "AINFO",
                    "Hospital is " + (a.getHospital()).getName() +
                            "\n\tConvenio is " + (a.getConvenio()).getNomeConvenio() +
                            "\n\tProcedimento is " + (a.getProcedimento()).getNameProcedimento());
        }
    }

    private void addSomeData() {

        if(allDao.getRoomHospitalRowCount() < 1) {

            RoomHospital[] hospitals = new RoomHospital[]{

            };

            allDao.insertRoomHospitals(new RoomHospital[]
                    {
                    new RoomHospital("Hospital 1"),
                    new RoomHospital("Hospital 2"),
                    new RoomHospital("Hospital 3")
            });

            allDao.insertRoomConvenios(new RoomConvenio[]
                    {
                        new RoomConvenio("Conv 1"),
                        new RoomConvenio("Conv 2"),
                        new RoomConvenio(" Conv 3")
                    });
            allDao.insertRoomProcedimentos(new RoomProcedimento[]
                    {
                            new RoomProcedimento("Proc 1"),
                            new RoomProcedimento("Proc 2"),
                            new RoomProcedimento("Proc 3")
                    });
            allDao.insertRoomLancamento(new RoomLancamento(2,1,3));
            allDao.insertRoomLancamento(new RoomLancamento(1,1,1));
        }
    }
}
```

This when run :-

1. builds the database
2. Calls the addSomeData method to load some data in none exists.

   1. 3 hospitals, 3 Convenios, 3 Procedimentos and 2 Lancamentos.
3. A List of Lancamentos is then extracted (all 2 of them).
4. An empty ArrayList 's is created.
5. The List of Lancamentos is then looped through building the respective AllTogether objects.
6. The resultant ArrayList of AllTogether objects is then looped through output the Hospital, Convenio and Procedimento names to the log.

### Result the above results in the expected out of :-

```
2019-09-30 16:10:19.546 D/AINFO: Hospital is Hospital 2
        Convenio is Conv 1
        Procedimento is Proc 3
2019-09-30 16:10:19.546 D/AINFO: Hospital is Hospital 1
        Convenio is Conv 1
        Procedimento is Proc 1
```